# Should prefetching return any faults at all?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to see if I have a correct understanding of prefetching with Core Data. I'm executing a fetch request with a batchSize of 20 for a Message object, with has a to-one relationship with a MBDate property. I prefetch this property:

```
[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:
           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"date", nil]];
```

The prefetch command goes through, as shown by this output:

```
CoreData: annotation: Prefetching with key 'date'.  Got 9 rows.
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0094s for 20 rows
```

However, in just the first batch, if I do

`if(message.date.isFault) NSLog(@"isFault");`,

it always outputs `isFault`, even though I prefetched it! And if I try to access any of the properties of the MBDate object, a fault request fires:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDATE, t0.ZDATESTRING FROM ZMBDATE t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0008s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0014s for 1 rows.
CoreData: annotation: fault fulfilled from database for : 0x85d22b0 <x-coredata://736D04C4-7DB3-40B7-B208-79B5DFD68260/MBDate/p61>
```

Why is the prefetch not going through? Why are my objects still faults?
I know it's hard to give any definite answers, but any tips or ideas would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this same thing without setting batch size?

There is a curious note in NSFetchRequest Class Reference under *fetchBatchSize*:

> If you set a non-zero batch size, the collection of objects returned
>   when the fetch is executed is broken into batches. When the fetch is
>   executed, the entire request is evaluated and the identities of all
>   matching objects recorded, but no more than batchSize objects’ data
>   will be fetched from the persistent store at a time. The array
>   returned from executing the request will be a proxy object that
>   transparently faults batches on demand.

It's as if you set batchSize the objects returned will be faulted no matter what.

Comment: But see it was faulting at a rate much smaller than my batch size, like every 5 objects it was faulting, when my batch size was 100. I ended up running a separate fetch to fetch my dates and place them in an array, which will automatically "prefetch" them for me without doing anything else